# where can I find the rake tasks delivered with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for tasks like tmp:clear or db:migrate. Where can I find the code for these tasks. I remember seeing them before but don't recollect where.

Also, is there a way I can set some global variables in a .rake file that can be accessed by all tasks 
in that file without passing them as arguments to each task.

thanks,
ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out where you installed Rails.

```
$ gem environment
```

Look for the INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY.

```
$ cd [INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY]/gems/rails-[VERSION]/lib/tasks
```

Look for the .rake files in the tasks directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#command-line-basics) as a starting point.